# does `intent.putExtra` overridede the last extra?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

if i call eg.

```
  intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key", value1);
```

and later `intent.putExtra("key", value2);`
will the receiver get *value1* or *value2*?
and if it will get value 1, how can i change that?

im am passing with `AlarmManager`

thanks for helping
Florian

Comment: "will the receiver get value1 or value2?" -- that depends entirely on when you do something with the `Intent`. If you use `startActivity()` before `putExtra("key", value2)`, then the receiver will get value1. If you use `startActivity()` after `putExtra("key", value2)`, then the receiver will get value2.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am reading "busy coders guide" fat but very nice book basically covers most of the things, great books thanks , are you coming with any new book in which you make complete apps, in most books the they make little demo apps, is there any book in which the actual process of design and best practices with some useful apps are provided.

Comment: @TheGoldy: I do not know what your comment has to do with this question. [*Exploring Android*](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore) is my tutorial-based book for building an app.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry it had nothing to do with this question , but i am a fan i just wanted to thanks for knowledge i get from CommonsWare books , so i just commented here , because i live in india i don't think i am ever going have honor to meet Mr. Mark Murphy say thanks in person

Comment: @TheGoldy: Um, you're welcome!